# Passing Multiple Variables Through Pages PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

The following code is working fine for the first page. It is a query based on user input from a form. I have 2 issues. The first one is when i click next page i get undefined index and undefined variable error which means the variables are not passed. The second question is how can i make a query and paginate it based on the user filled/selected values in the form? Some users may not fill all the values.
Here is my code: NB: The form method is GET. I have tried REQUEST and POST too. All the same error. Thanks in advance guys.

```
<?php   

    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
    $age = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['age']);
    $height = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['height']);

    include_once "conn.php"; //connect to db and table

    $rs = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people WHERE name='$name' AND email='$email' AND age='$age' AND height='$height'"); 
    $rw = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    $numrows = $rw[0];
if ($numrows== 0) die("No Results Found");

$rowsperpage = 7;

$totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);


if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {

   $currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];
} else {

   $currentpage = 1;
} 
if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {

   $currentpage = $totalpages;
} 
if ($currentpage < 1) {

   $currentpage = 1;
} 
$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name='$name' AND email='$email' AND age='$age' AND height='$height' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage"); 

//print my tables here 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
               {       
                   $uniqueid = $row['age'];
//output stuff here   
               }
//close sql
$range = 3;
if ($currentpage > 1) {
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1&amp;name=$name&amp;email=$email&amp;age=$age&amp;height=$height'> Go To Page 1</a> ";

   $prevpage = $currentpage - 1;

   echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage&amp;name=$name&amp;email=$email&amp;age=$age&amp;height=$height'> Previous Page</a>";
} 
for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++) {

   if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {

      if ($x == $currentpage) {

         echo " &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size=4 color=red>[<b>$x</b>] </font>";

      } else {

         echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$x&amp;name=$name&amp;email=$email&amp;age=$age&amp;height=$height'>$x</a>";
      } 
   }  
}        
if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {

   $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;

   echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage&amp;name=$name&amp;email=$email&amp;age=$age&amp;height=$height'>Next Page</font></a>";

   echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$totalpages&amp;name=$name&amp;email=$email&amp;age=$age&amp;height=$height'>Last Page</a> ";
} 

?>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You're passing on variables like type, make, model, price but trying to get vars like name, email, age and height. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Ynhockey thanks for the note. Mistyped the code here. Edited now. Kindly assist where you can.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @koala_dev thanks for the headz up. Will work on that. Anything on the subject matter?

Comment: Yes, your first `if`, why are you checking for a $_POST variable? also it is missing any braces so it will just affect the next line. Also `$numrows = $rw[0];` if you're trying to get the number of rows from your query then use `$numrows = is_array($rw)? count($rw) : 0;` Finally I think it will help if you shows an example of the markup that is generated with your php so we get a better idea of your problem

Comment: @koala_dev the error i am getting when i click next is Undefined index name at line .... Undefined variable name at line .... Undefined index email at line .... Undefined variable email at line .... Undefined index age at line .... Undefined variable age at line ....

Comment: What line is that? and what I actually meant was if you can shows us the HTML markup that is being echoed/output in the browser

Comment: FWIW, when developing this stiuff, I use Firefox's firebug extension. A tool like that will make it much easier for you te see what's actually being passed to the page, and pick up on a number of other common errors. Also, take another look at sessions.

Answer (score 0):

The form submits as GET. Because this one, the POST variable isn't set. And you're not defining the first variable (missing brackets?). Furthermore, `Submit` is the only submitted value with a capital. Is this intentional?

```
if (isset($_GET['Submit'])) {
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
    $age = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['age']);
    $height = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['height']);
}
```

More ideally, because you want to ommit values, you'll probably want to check each variable individually for existence. And if it's not set (or [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)), don't add that field in your WHERE clause.

```
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']) : null;
// ... process the other fields in same way ...
```

or spanned over multiple lines: *EDIT: just noticed I was missing a closing `)` in the two blocks below.*

```
$name = null;
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
}

// ... process the other fields in same way ...
```

or even:

```
$name = null;
if (isset($_GET['name']))
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);

// ... process the other fields in same way ...
```

### Dynamic query

Then, make your query a bit more dynamic. Like, adding all your available WHERE parameters to an array. It makes things easier.

```
// Store conditions in array
$whereConditions = array();

if (!empty($name)) {
    $whereConditions['name'] = $name;
}

if (!empty($email)) {
    $whereConditions['email'] = $email;
}

if ($age && $age > 0) {
    $whereConditions['age'] = $age;
}

if ($height && $height > 0) {
    $whereConditions['height'] = $height;
}

// Start building your query dynamically
$query = 'SELECT * FROM people';


// Making things easier here. Just flatten your array down.
$conditions = array();
foreach ($whereConditions as $field => $value) {
    $conditions[] = sprintf("%s = '%s'", $field, $value);
}

// Join all conditions with AND
$where = implode(' AND ', $conditions);

// Add where clause, if there are conditions
if (!empty($where)) {
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . $where;
}

$query .= " ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT {$offset}, {$rowsperpage}";
```

### Final notes

Keep in mind to use prepared queries if you're allowing user input. And the `mysql_` extension is deprecated. Switch to `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Comment: @UrGuardian4Angel. Thanks for pointing out these issues. I am not sure how to check if all variables are set and if so how to conduct the sql search based on set variables. Kindly guide Thanks

Comment: Okay. I'll try to adapt the example a bit, if you want? ;)

Comment: @koala_dev. I have made the changes as you said and i can see some changes. I am working on UrGuardian4ngel input above and update you ASAP. Once again appreciate your time and efforts

Comment: Oops... I was missing a `)` in the third and forth block... Updated code.

Comment: @ UrGuardian4ngel i have hit a dead end completely. Please help by taking me step by step. Lets start with how to make a query based on user input

Comment: What do you mean? The last code block generates a query, based on the user input. Each field that is filled in by the user (so it's not empty), gets added to the array `whereConditions`. We're using the field as key and the user input as value. Afterwards, we loop through this array, and we concatenate the contents (key and value) in a single condition string, using the format `fieldname = 'value'`. This is added to a helper array, `$conditions`. The 'single condition strings' get glued together using the ' AND ' keyword. After that you just paste it behind the query.

Comment: So i can use $conditions as follows...."SELECT * people '$conditions'. I am a embryo in php mysql...not even near a newbie!!!!!!!

Comment: no you can't do that. `$conditions` is an array. The next step converts that array to a string, separated by AND. It would be more something like `"SELECT * FROM people WHERE {$where}"`

Comment: I thought the code should first generate the user input then do the query. Still in the woods

Comment: The user input is 'generated' by the user, on form submit. Those input is loaded in the variables like `$name`, `$email`, ... You just want to make sure you'll filter your database results using only filled filter fields.

Comment: @ UrGuardian4ngel i have tried everything including having tha array $where. Now i get this error Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: Means the query is invalid. Try using `var_dump($query)` to see what's wrong with the query yourself, or check which error message `var_dump(mysql_error())` returns. Fix that error, and try again. Repeat until it works.